# A function that creates two dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I wanted to create a function that creates a two dimensional dynamic array. so i wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void make_mat (double *** , int, int);
int main(){
    int m = 3, n = 4;
    double **a;
    make_mat(&a,m,n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}

void make_mat( double ***x , int m , int n){
    *x = new double *[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        *x[i] = new double [n];
    }
}
```

There's no syntax errors in the codes but i get following error after compiling:

> Unhandled exception at 0x003657E6 in ConsoleApplication20.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Totally this is not a good way for creating a function that creates two dimensional dynamic array. is there any better idea or any correction on the code above?

Comment: Defining gloval `void main()` is illegal in standard C++. You should use `int main()` if there aren't any special reason to use non-standard `main()` function type.

Comment: ok i'll edit it now

Comment: Yes, there's a better idea. Use the flying `std::vector`.

Comment: is it easier to just use a 1D std::vector and then map 2D indices to indices over the 1D vector? Or just use libraries like Eigen, Armadillo, etc

Comment: in fact i'm still not familiar with vectors

Comment: Why muck with three star programming? Go `double ** make_mat (int, int);`

Comment: Forget this pointer nonsense, please. Familiarise yourself with `std::vector`.

Comment: Your `j` is counting up to `m` and it should be to `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*x[i]` is equivalent to `*(x[i])`, which is equivalent to `x[i][0]`.

You should use `(*x)[i]` instead of `*x[i]` in the function `make_mat()`.

Comment: `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`. `**(x+i)` is equivalent to `*(x[i])`, which is equivalent to `x[i][0]`. It is not equivalent to `(*x)[i]`, which is equivalent to `x[0][i]`.